# Where are the secret levels on Reed?

Tags: reed

After completion, [Reed](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.PXLink.Reed) has five secret achievements which [apparently](https://twitter.com/PXLink/status/883592638414376960) correspond to five hidden levels.

In order of increasing spolieryness:

- is there any hint or marker for where a secret level may be in-game?
- which regular levels contain hidden levels?
- where exactly are the entrances to the hidden levels?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> “[The game has 5 secret levels, for each level is given achievement](https://twitter.com/PXLink/status/883592638414376960)” — [@PXLink Twitter](https://twitter.com/PXLink)

There are no indications of where they are located, and it is impossible to re-enter a secret level (unless you clear your saved game progress).

To enter such secret locations, just jump into the right spot.

- 8, above the moving platform, at the ceiling of the pyramid-shaped area (Secret letter "R"!)
- 19, at the bottom right (Secret letter "E"!)
- 27, at the top middle, to the right of the middle saw, but only works if you have not touched the cube (Secret letter "E"!)
- 40, near the NPC (Secret letter "D"!)
- 47, near the NPC (Secret word "REEDIUM"!)

Comment: Can confirm that 40 is D, and on this list I found that 19 is E and 47 is "Reedium". I guess the five aren't A-E then. I'll have another pass over this list later. Thanks!

Comment: I've reset my save and played through the levels yet again. There is one level remaining.

Comment: 8 gave me real trouble! But yes, got there in the end.

Comment: Final update. The developer explained the secret from level 27.

Comment: Confirmed worked. That might be a requirement for all of them but I don't remember whether it was an issue.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there any indication or how did you find ALL of them? I noticed the suspicious pyramid on L8 and the strange NPC position on L40 on my own, but without your answer I surely won't find the other three.

Comment: See my answer. There is indication about them, yet subtle.

Answer (score 2):

The correct locations of all five entries is given in the accepted answer. But I'd like to add that there actually **ARE** indications about entries. See the screenshots taken from L19 and L40. There's a really subtle glowing dark light (animated) at the entry. It disappears after you enter it once.

The first image is taken from L19 and the second image is taken from L40. The other three are really hard to notice with bare eyes.

[image: L19]

[image: L40]

I can also confirm that the requirement "before touching the cube" applies to all five levels, not just L27. In any level if you touch the cube first, the entry will disappear even if you haven't entered it.

Answer (score 1):

The last secret is at level 27, as shown in the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: It seems this question is asking for all of them though.  Unless this is the only one, this doesn't fully answer the question.

Comment: @TimmyJim If between us we can list them all, that's good enough for me...

Comment: Any tips for getting there? I've got right up in there a couple of times and nothing has happened.

Comment: Олег Косовцов is the developer of this game. ;)
I think there is a bug in the game, because [nothing happens when I go there](https://youtu.be/2j_gopYENEQ).